# Issue when updating XML to varchar SQL column

Tags: c#, xml

I am updating some XML via code in C# and when I insert it into my database (varchar column) I am seeing a extra ?. I think this has to do with the Encoding.UTF8 I am doing. The ? is NOT there all the way through the process of calling SaveChanges() in EF core.

The database column in varchar and cannot be changed due to the way it was set up etc.

I'm not sure how I should convert the xml back to string after saving it from the dashboard (which is dev express)

```
      internal static async Task<string> ConvertXmlToNewConnectionStrings(string xml, List<ConnectionSourceViewModel> connectionSourceViews, int currentUserId)
        {
            var connectionStringOptions = await GetConnectionStringOptions(currentUserId).ConfigureAwait(false);

            System.Xml.Linq.XDocument doc;
            using (StringReader s = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(s);
            }

            Dashboard d = new Dashboard();
            d.LoadFromXDocument(doc);
            var sqlDataSources = d.DataSources.OfType<DashboardSqlDataSource>().ToList();

            foreach (var item in sqlDataSources)
            {
                // We do not want the properties in the data source anymore... this includes user name and password etc... the new way dev ex went with this functionality
                item.ConnectionParameters = null;

                // get the selected connection string from the end user
                var connectionStringId = connectionSourceViews.Where(x => x.SqlDataSourceComponentName == item.ComponentName).Select(x => x.SelectedConnectionStringId).FirstOrDefault();

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionStringId) == false)
                {
                    item.ConnectionName = connectionStringOptions.Where(x => x.Value == connectionStringId).Select(x => x.Text).FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            d.SaveToXml(ms);
            byte[] array = ms.ToArray();
            ms.Close();
            xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array, 0, array.Length);

            return xml;
        }
```

I'm expecting the ? is not be added to the XML in the database column of varchar after saving it via EF Core

Image of ? at start:
https://ibb.co/LZ2QVtr

Comment: It is a non printable character probably a SOH.

Comment: @jdweng It might be, but it is being ready when I read in the XML into my application and it is causing errors :-(

Comment: It has to be removed.  First find out the hex value of the character.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks. I'll report back once I figure out how to remove it after it is added in when saving via EF Core etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up removing the code that does a MemoryStream() and went to saving the document back to the XDocument().

```
doc = d.SaveToXDocument();
```

Now everything works fine and no question mark (?) is put in the database!